# Segfault converting string to int in RISC V

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, riscv

I need to implement a function `convert` manually in RISC V assembly.

```
int convert(char*);

input: a string may or may not contain '+' or '-'.
If a non-digit character appears anywhere in the string, return -1.

=========

output: int number

for example:
 
Input:
 
+123

+0000000123

-123

-0000000321

2147483647

2147483648

-2147483648

-123123AAA

+123123AAA

123123AAA


Output:

123

123

-123

-321

2147483647

-2147483648

-2147483648

-1

-1

-1 
 
=========
```

This is the C code that will call my function `convert`:

```c
int convert(char *);
int main(){
    char input[SIZE];
    int out;

    while ( scanf("%s", input) != EOF  ) {
        out = convert(input);
        printf("%d\n", out);
    }
    
    printf("%s\n","The end");
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the way I would ideally write `convert()` in C:

```c
int convert(char *AS){
    int num=0;
    int dec=0;
    int i=0;
    int neg = 0;
    int j=0;

    while(AS[j] != '\0')
    {
        num = AS[j];
        if(i==0 && num == '+')//'+' is 43
        {
            i++;
            j++;

            continue;
        }
        if( i==0 && num == '-')//'-' is 45
        {
            neg = 1;
            i++;
            j++;
            continue;
        }
        if( num<48 || num>57 )//digit is 48-57
        {

            return -1;
        }

        dec = dec*10 + (num-48);
        i=2;
        j++;
    }
    if(neg == 1){
        dec = dec *(-1);
    }

    return dec;
}
```

Here is my attempt to write `convert.s` in RISC V assembly:

```
# int convert(char *);

convert:
add a7, zero, zero
add a2, zero, zero
add a3, zero, zero
add a4, zero, zero
add a5, zero, zero
#addi a7, zero, 48
add t6, a0, zero

Loop:
add a6, t6, zero
#add a1, zero, zero
add a6, a6, a5
lb a7, 0(a6)
beq a7, zero, Exit

addi t3, zero, 43
bne a3, zero, Label1
bne a7, t3, Label1
addi a3, a3, 1
addi a5, a5, 1
beq zero, zero, Loop

Label1:
addi t3, zero, 45
bne a3, zero, Label2
bne a7, t3, Label2
addi a4, zero, 1
addi a3, a3, 1
addi a5, a5, 1
beq zero, zero, Loop

Label2:
addi t4, zero, 48
addi t5, zero, 57
blt a7, t4, Label3
blt t5, a7, Label3
beq zero, zero, Label4

Label3:
addi a0, zero, -1
ret

Label4:
addi t3, zero, 10
mul a2, a2, t3
addi t4, zero, 48
sub a7, a7, t4
add a2, a2, a7

addi a3, zero, 2
addi a5, a5, 1
j Loop

Exit:
add a0,a2,zero
addi t3, zero, 1
beq a4, t3, Label5
beq zero, zero, Label6
Label5:
addi t3, zero, -1
mul a0, a0, t3
Label6:
ret
```

However, I got a segfault error message after I print out the answer:

```
z  0000000000000000 ra 0000000000000000 sp 000000007f7e9b50 gp 0000000000000000
tp 0000000000000000 t0 0000000000000000 t1 0000000000001000 t2 00002190000300aa
s0 0000000000000000 s1 0000000000000000 a0 0000000000000000 a1 0000000010024a40
a2 0000000000000008 a3 0000000000000000 a4 0000000000000000 a5 0000000000000001
a6 000000000000000a a7 0000000000000040 s2 0000000000000000 s3 0000000000000000
s4 0000000000000000 s5 0000000000000000 s6 0000000000000000 s7 0000000000000000
s8 0000000000000000 s9 0000000000000000 sA 0000000000000000 sB 0000000000000000
t3 000000000000006c t4 0000000000000068 t5 0000000000000064 t6 000000007f7e9b30
pc 0000000000000000 va 0000000000000000 insn       ffffffff sr 8000000200046020
User fetch segfault @ 0x0000000000000000
make: *** [Makefile:6: test] Error 255
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is the output at the top an example from the assignment or is that actual output of your program? Does your code print something at least? Since the dump shows `pc=0` that hints at return address corruption but your `convert` function seems harmless in that respect. Can you single step in a debugger/simulator? How far does it go? What is `SIZE`? Note you should be doing safe input respecting that limit.

Comment: I really appreciate for your comment.
The output at the top is an example and is also my output.
So, I also guess my convert function can work.
I want to use a debugger but I always stick in an instruction “n”, which is an instruction that can move to the next line of code.
Everytime I use “n” in gdb(the debugger), it wait for a long time and do nothing.
I really don’t know why.
The Input length is at most 15 bytes. And the return value will be printed out in 32bit-int format.

Comment: You can use `ni` for instructions or `s` or `si` to step into functions. Since you don't seem to get the `"The end"` printed maybe put a breakpoint on that line to see if that is reachable.

Comment: Sorry, I now notice that my assembly code is not explained well.
a1 -> num, 
a2 -> dec, 
a3 -> i, 
a4 -> neg, 
a5 -> j, 
and when I move from AS[0] to AS[1], I only need to add a byte in address.

Comment: did your C code work?

Comment: My assembly code can get the correct int answer ant print out The end. But after "The end", the error come out. And when I test in codeblock, my C code can work. Is that possible for me to edit the whole article above to make it clearer?

Comment: That sounds like buffer overflow. Double check that `SIZE` is correct and that you are not entering more data. Specifying the limit in the format or use `fgets` instead.

Comment: SIZE is set to 15in the question. But in my code, I check out when to leave the while loop by '\0' the SIZE should not be the problem?

Comment: The buffer overflow happens if `scanf` reads more input than 15 bytes. It's not in your assembly code.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that now. I try to define the SIZE to be 18 or more to give it a bigger space, but segfault is still there. Maybe scanf is not the problem. Is there any other error could cause this?

Comment: Use the debugger to single step or put a breakpoint at the `return 0;`. Verify return address. If it's wrong put a memory write watch on it to see who corrupts it. Your conversion code only does a memory read that should not be able to overwrite anything.

Comment: Thank you very much! I found the answer. My assembly code is correct. But I've modified Makefile to use debugger, that's the reason my code crush.